# CSS not work in Javafx WebStart mode

Tags: java, css, web, javafx

my problem is when i compile and run the code in Standalone mode it use the .css getStylesheets in my Scene , but when i run it in the WebStart nothing is applyed just the standard look of  JavaFx .

even if i use :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/e1/login.css").toExternalForm());
```

the error given by the java console in the web browser is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at e1.E1.start(E1.java:68)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown
```

and the same code is working in the Standalone mode

please helpppppppp me !!!!!!

Comment: i tryed to print the content of :getClass().getResource("/e1/login.css").toExternalForm() , so it give Null

Comment: i can't load my css style please help !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To load a stylesheet, assuming you're applying it to your scene.  Example code below...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    HBox pane = new HBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    scene.getStylesheets().add("/test.css");

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```